# SQL create a column based on Groupby condition

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, partition

I'm trying to see if an event appears more than once in a table within a month and assign a boolean logic 0 for 'No' and 1 for 'Yes'.

Example table:

| Event | Event date |
| --- | --- |
| Turn | 2021-01-24 |
| Turn | 2021-01-25 |
| Turn | 2021-03-14 |
| Turn | 2021-04-21 |
| Stop | 2020-05-20 |
| Stop | 2021-05-20 |
| Stop | 2021-05-24 |
| Start | 2021-05-23 |
| Start | 2021-05-24 |
| Start | 2021-05-24 |

Example output:

| Event | Event date | Returning? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Turn | 2021-01-24 | 1 |
| Turn | 2021-01-25 | 1 |
| Turn | 2021-03-14 | 0 |
| Turn | 2021-04-21 | 0 |
| Stop | 2020-03-20 | 0 |
| Stop | 2021-03-20 | 1 |
| Stop | 2021-03-24 | 1 |
| Stop | 2021-05-31 | 0 |
| Start | 2021-05-23 | 1 |
| Start | 2021-05-24 | 1 |
| Start | 2021-05-24 | 1 |

create table test (Event varchar (20), a date)

```
insert into #test(Event, Event date)
values
('Turn','2021-01-24'),
('Turn','2021-01-25'),
('Turn','2021-03-14'),
('Turn','2021-04-21'),
('Stop','2020-05-20'),
('Stop','2021-05-20'),
('Stop','2021-05-24'),
('Start','2021-05-23'),
('Start','2021-05-24'),
('Start','2021-05-24'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a window function:

```
select t.*,
       (count(*) over (partition by event, year(date), month(date)) > 1) as returning
from t;
```

Comment: @Tin_Evans . . . No.  The `> 1` makes this a boolean expression.